# How do I make a copy command to have a prompt as well?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

```
Directory of C:\Test\Cmds

09/23/2017  10:53 PM    <DIR>          .
09/23/2017  10:53 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/23/2017  10:53 PM                 4 Test1234
               1 File(s)              4 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  90,126,499,840 bytes free

C:\Test\Cmds>xcopy C:\Test\Cmds\Test1234 C:\Test\Cmds \p
Invalid number of parameters
```

Still getting used to this if this is the incorrect way to format please let me know as I wish to learn more from others here while making it as easy as possible for you all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is telling you there are invalid number of parameter is because you used the backslash on your `p` option, which `xcopy` treats as a 3rd parameter instead of treating it as an option.

The correct command should be:
`C:\Test\Cmds>xcopy C:\Test\Cmds\Test1234 C:\Test\Cmds /p`